# Lazy load map when they come into the viewport

Tags: javascript, lazy-loading, viewport

I am trying to load a Google Map map only when it is displayed on the viewport.

I have heard a lot about the "lazy loading" principle, but I must admit that I start in javascript.

My code works perfectly on desktop, but I would like that my mobile site is much better.

Here is my code:

```
        function initMap() {
        var loc = {lat: 45.764043, lng: 4.835658999999964};
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: loc
        });
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        var coordinate = document.getElementsByClassName('datajson');
        for (var i = 0; i < coordinate.length; i++) {
            (function (index) {
                var elements = JSON.parse(coordinate[i].value);
                var localisation={lat: elements.latitude, lng: elements.longitude};
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position:localisation,
                    map: map
                });
                bounds.extend(localisation);
            })(i);
        }
        map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter());
        map.setZoom(10);  
    }

    function loadScript() {
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXXXX&'+'callback=initMap';
        document.body.appendChild(script);
    }

    window.onload = loadScript;
```

I would like to have your opinion on the way to do and possible improvements if possible.

I thank you in advance

Comment: what are you missing on mobile?

Comment: in fact I would like the card to load only when I arrive on it, only when the user sees it on his screen

Comment: ok then, my answer should be the one to accept ;-)

Comment: indeed, I succeeded thanks to your answer, and I thank you ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your approach is ok. for simplicity, you could do the same, with an `<script async>` of the google js api, omiting the `loadScript` function.

but. lazy loading normally means "loading on demand", so, as you say, for example when the map will come into the viewport, whereas your `loadScript` is called immediatly after the page has loaded. there are libraries, for example the [waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/) one, or [scrollmonitor](https://github.com/stutrek/scrollMonitor), or you do it yourself. either way, `loadScript` then again is of use.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for an answer to this, and I've ended up creating this solution:

```
var googleMapLoaded = false;
$(window).on('scroll', function(){
    if(googleMapLoaded === false && $(window).scrollTop() > $('#map').position().top - $(window).height()) {
        googleMapLoaded = true;
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXXXX&callback=initMap';
        document.body.appendChild(script);
    }
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here is my working example on vanilla js, reworked from Bandi answer.

```
var googleMapLoaded = false;
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){
    if (googleMapLoaded === false && 
           window.scrollY > document.querySelector('#map').getBoundingClientRect().top - window.innerHeight) {
        googleMapLoaded = true;
        const script = document.createElement('script');
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        script.src = '//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXXXX&callback=initMap';
        document.body.appendChild(script);
    }
});
```